# Why is a closure using the `move` keyword not inferred as FnOnce?

Tags: rust, closures

I am playing with examples from [Understanding Closures in Rust.](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-closures-in-rust-21f286ed1759). I defined the following structure:

```
struct MyStruct {
    text: &'static str,
    number: u32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new(text: &'static str, number: u32) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            text: text,
            number: number,
        }
    }
    // We have to specify that 'self' is an argument.
    fn get_number(&self) -> u32 {
        self.number
    }
    // We can specify different kinds of ownership and mutability of self.
    fn inc_number(&mut self) {
        self.number += 1;
    }
    // There are three different types of 'self'
    fn destructor(self) {
        println!("Destructing {}", self.text);
    }
}
```

I created these "testing" functions to classify a closure based on compile time errors:

```
fn is_fn<A, R>(_x: fn(A) -> R) {}
fn is_Fn<A, R, F: Fn(A) -> R>(_x: &F) {}
fn is_FnMut<A, R, F: FnMut(A) -> R>(_x: &F) {}
fn is_FnOnce<A, R, F: FnOnce(A) -> R>(_x: &F) {}
```

The article demonstrates following example as a `FnOnce` closure:

```
let obj1 = MyStruct::new("Hello", 15);
let obj2 = MyStruct::new("More Text", 10);
// obj1 is owned by the closure
let mut closure4 = move |x: &MyStruct| {
    obj1.destructor();
    x.get_number()
};
is_FnMut(&closure4);
```

This has a compilation error:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:36:24
   |
36 |     let mut closure4 = move |x: &MyStruct| {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`
37 |         obj1.destructor();
   |         ---- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `obj1` out of its environment
...
40 |     is_FnMut(&closure4);
   |     -------- the requirement to implement `FnMut` derives from here
```

That makes sense. From my understanding, the compiler infers that the value is moved into the closure because the destructor is called.

I was trying to see what else causes the closure to be inferred as `FnOnce`. I declared the closure as a `move` closure:

```
let obj1 = MyStruct::new("Hello", 15);
let obj2 = MyStruct::new("More Text", 10);
// obj1 is owned by the closure
let mut closure4 = move |x: &MyStruct| {
    obj1.get_number();
    x.get_number()
};
is_Fn(&closure4);
is_FnMut(&closure4);
```

To my surprise, this actually passes, so this closure is actually considered to be also `Fn`, not exclusively `FnOnce` as I expected. Why is that? I thought if a value is moved into closure, it wouldn't implement `Fn` but only `FnOnce`.

So I though, "Okay, maybe somehow `obj1` is not really moved into the closure, let me test that". So I tried to use `obj1` in any way after constructing `closure4`, the compiler indicates that `obj1` was indeed moved into the closure:

```
let obj1 = MyStruct::new("Hello", 15);
let obj2 = MyStruct::new("More Text", 10);
// obj1 is owned by the closure
let mut closure4 = move |x: &MyStruct| {
    obj1.get_number();
    x.get_number()
};
obj1.get_number();
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `obj1`
  --> src/main.rs:40:5
   |
33 |     let obj1 = MyStruct::new("Hello", 15);
   |         ---- move occurs because `obj1` has type `MyStruct`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
36 |     let mut closure4 = move |x: &MyStruct| {
   |                        ------------------- value moved into closure here
37 |         obj1.get_number();
   |         ---- variable moved due to use in closure
...
40 |     obj1.get_number();
   |     ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Can someone enlighten this behaviour for me? What must hold true for a closure to implement none of `fn`, `Fn`, `FnMut`, but only implement `FnOnce`?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: the **body** of the closure determines what traits are implemented. Your closure only takes references to the value, so it can be called multiple times.